# Is it possible to reopen a question and then recommend it is moved to another stack exchange?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering what the protocol is for questions that have been closed as *“unclear what you're asking”* then have been edited to make the question clearer, but once edited the question is clearly better suited for another stack exchange.

For example there was a question about certificates recently that was closed as it was unclear what the question was, once edited it appeared in the reopen moderation queue, however it had become clear that the question was about mass deployment of certificates and would probably have been better suited to server fault stack exchange.

In cases like this, is better practice to reopen the question then flag it as being off topic and in need of migration, or is it better to vote to leave the question closed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What the mods can do is to re-open then move. But we need to know about it. Flag it with a custom message.

Comment: Can this be done from the re-open queue? I cannot see the option to flag on that page?

Comment: Not from the queue but should be possible on the question itself

Comment: Ah yes it can, the options are more limited than normal however.

Comment: @TheJulyPlot done